# LoginComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object object Object

Tags: angular, jsonplaceholder

I have a trivial problem.Client app is on Angular 8 and the game is that I try to get users from jsonplaceholder api.Its look simple but everythink that I try does not work.My request looks like:

```
getAll(model: any):Observable<User[]>{
return this.http.get<User[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
```

}

and in the component:

```
getAll() {
return this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((users: User[]) =>
  this.users$ = users);
```

}

This my User:

```
export interface User {
id: number;
name: string;
username: string;
email: string;
address:Address;
geo:Geo;
phone: string;
website: string;
company:Company;
```

}
And HTML:

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">

<select id="users$" name="users$" [(ngModel)]="users$" class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let user of users$" value="user.id">{{user.name | json}}</option>
</select>
<tr *ngFor="let user of users$">
  <td>{{user}}</td>
</tr>
```

The error from response is: LoginComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling the wrong method which returns an Object, change the method to call  **`getAll`**

```
getAll() {
       return this.userService.getAll().subscribe((users: User[]) => {
       this.users$ = users);
    };
}
```

Comment: With fetch() is work like a charm and https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users return me all users.But my target is to use TypeScript